# How to use council's external proposal correctly?

Tags: council

While testing the council functionality, I ran into an error with `BadOrigin`.

Where is the mistake?

Below are my steps:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you share the runtime you are using? `set_balance` requires Root origin, and it looks like you don't have the Democracy included that would dispatch the call as root.

Answer (score 3):

I found the reason.

[image]

The threshold is set to 3 on the polkadot.js apps UI, but in fact, according to the origin rule in the substrate code, it cannot be executed.

runtime.lib

```
type ExternalMajorityOrigin =
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 3, 4>;
```

frame/collective/src/lib.rs

```
pub struct EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, I: 'static, const N: u32, const D: u32>(
    PhantomData<(AccountId, I)>,
);
impl<
        O: Into<Result<RawOrigin<AccountId, I>, O>> + From<RawOrigin<AccountId, I>>,
        AccountId,
        I,
        const N: u32,
        const D: u32,
    > EnsureOrigin<O> for EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, I, N, D>
{
    type Success = ();
    fn try_origin(o: O) -> Result<Self::Success, O> {
        o.into().and_then(|o| match o {
            RawOrigin::Members(n, m) if n * D >= N * m => Ok(()),
            r => Err(O::from(r)),
        })
    }

    #[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
    fn try_successful_origin() -> Result<O, ()> {
        Ok(O::from(RawOrigin::Members(0u32, 0u32)))
    }
}
```

We can solve it by the two ways:

1. change the origin rule.
2. go to develop - extrinsic to set the threshold.

For 1,

```
type ExternalMajorityOrigin =
        pallet_collective::EnsureProportionAtLeast<AccountId, CouncilCollective, 1, 2>;
```

For 2.

[image]

All in all, the rules of threshold and origin need to be consistent.